# How to install a library when I have its source code?

Tags: 12.04, libraries

I want to include some libraries in my project like json-glib, beecrypt or libffi.
 Usually, I install all the libraries using `sudo apt-get install XYZ`.
But sometimes, I get a `.tar` file of any library which I extract at some place on my desktop.
I don't know how to install these type of libraries for which I have the source code. I get the installed files in `/usr/include` or sometimes in `/usr/lib` folder when I install using the above command written.
How to do it in case of source code?

Comment: Note that `/usr/include` contains the headers for the library, which you need if you wanted to write a program/library that uses this library and is only used during compilation, and that `/usr/lib` contains the library itself, which is needed to run something that uses that library. Also, note that some buildsystems install into the `/usr/local` prefix (which I prefer) instead of the `/usr` prefix.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the aforementioned question. A specific component is present here: the specification of the path for the library.
This question has blessed my day! :) So thanks @hellodear Chandramouli for useful contribution.

Comment: I agree and Sharath answered that particular part well ...

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to install a library which was downloaded in its source code form is:

1. Assuming you are in the home folder, extract the .tar, .tar.gz, .tar.bz2, .tar.xz file using,

   `tar xf source_filename`
2. Go to the folder /home/some_user/libxxx/ (the folder into which the previous tar command extracted the files)
3. Run,

   `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`

   `make`

   `sudo make install`

This installs the library in '/usr/local' which is the recommended path according to the convention when you are not installing a software via any package manager. Also, this will not pollute the existing libraries in '/usr/lib' which makes maintenance easy in case you wish to uninstall the library in future.

Comment: what is the difference if I will put the files in usr/local and /usr/lib and /usr/include? I am new to ubuntu. Elaborate this thing. Thanks.

Comment: `/usr/lib` is the path for compiled libraries, whereas `/usr/include` is the path where the C/C++ header files are stored which contain function prototypes to access the libraries. As already explained, there is no harm if you install the custom library in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local`, either should work. For custom libraries, `/usr/local` path is recommended only from administration perspective. Hope am clear.